# How link PhysFS with CMAKE?

Tags: c, cmake, sdl-2, archlinux, physfs

I'm trying to use the PhysFS in my game in C. I'm using CMake to generate the Makefile. CMake indicates well found the include folder and the lib, but I get an error during the build: undefined reference to "PHYSFS_init".

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(PROJECT_NAME "awesome-game")

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_mixer REQUIRED)
find_package(PhysFS REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_MIXER_DIRS})
include_directories(${PhysFS_DIRS})


file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS "src/*.h" "src/*.c")  
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} PRIVATE ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES} PRIVATE ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PhysFS_LIBRARY})

add_definitions(-DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED)
```

CMakeCache.txt :

```
//Path to a file.
PHYSFS_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include

//Path to a library.
PHYSFS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libphysfs.so

//Path to a library.
SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libSDL2main.a

//SDL2 directory
SDL2_DIR:PATH=

//Path to a file.
SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/SDL2

//Path to a library.
SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libSDL2_image.so

//Path to a file.
SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/SDL2

//Where the SDL Library can be found
SDL2_LIBRARY:STRING=/usr/lib/libSDL2.so;-lpthread

//Path to a file.
SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/SDL2

//Path to a library.
SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libSDL2_mixer.so
```

I have the header physfs.h at **/usr/local/include/physfs.h**

Comment: Is `libphysfs.s` the right extension? Should it be `libphysfs.a` or `libphysfs.so`?

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly copied the text, but it's physfs.so which is indicated in the file

Comment: In CMake variables names are **case-sensitive**: If you have variable `PHYSFS_LIBRARY`, then it should be referenced with `${PHYSFS_LIBRARY}`. The reference `${PhysFS_LIBRARY}` is wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work fine now!